How can DCI-P3 represent sRGB
DCI-P3 is not better than sRGB. Imagine DCI-P3 and sRGB as 2 cakes. Since both gamut can display the same number of colours this effectively means that we are cutting both the cakes into equal pieces but because the sRGB cake is smaller in size therefore sRGB cake has smaller pieces. This effectively means that sRGB has a lower least count that DCI-P3. Since, the content that is mostly available is in sRGB, why don't we use that colour gamut? Moreover, how can DCI-P3 represent sRGB since the pieces in DCI-P3 are bigger compared to the pieces in sRGB (the least count of sRGB is lower compared to DCI-P3)? If it cannot, then why is there an option to use sRGB in picture color mode of Android developer settings. I am assuming my device uses DCI-P3 color gamut because of this reason.

The question contains false assumptions. You should start to believe that both spaces are continuous, their specs contain nothing of how many discrete color samples practical display systems can present. Common 8 bit systems can present 16777216 samples, 16 bit systems multiply it by 16777216, but the number of the colors in both spaces is infinite. Every sRGB color is inside the DCI-P3 space. That's the way how DCI-P3 can represent sRGB.
Surely there exist some colors that a practical 8 bit/channel  sRGB display can show,but another practical 8 bit per channel DCI-P system cannot. A 16 bit/channel DCI-P system shows those colors so accurately that no human can see the error.

how can DCI-P3 represent sRGB since the pieces in DCI-P3 are bigger compared to the pieces in sRGB (the least count of sRGB is lower compared to DCI-P3)?
This was the main question

@AnshulGupta Ok. I rewrote the answer.

So, if a device has a 8-bit display then using DCI-P3 need not be a good choice over sRGB since a 8 bits can only display 2^8 colors. When we use DCI-P3 over the same colors, the size of slices of cake/ least count/ step size increases. I am talking about practical scenario not theoretical.

Think that colors shown by a practical display is a set of discrete point samples of the color space. The color space is not divided to pieces by them. If you have 8 bits per channel the number of available colors is 16777216, not 2^8. If you watch 8 bit/channel  sRGB color photos in 8 bit/channel DCI-P system you get still 16777216 colors, but they look exaggerated. Or if you have color manageement ON they are averagely right, but inaccurate. For sRGB material run the display in sRGB mode. That very likely is an option.

I apologise for my mistake I meant that for a 8 bit display the number of colours can be 2^82^82^8. Now since both the color gamut can display the same number of colours the size of slices of cake/ least count/ step size increases. Think of it as a 15 cms and 30 cms scale but the least count of 15 cms scale is 1 mm but the least count of 30 cms scale is 1 cm.

The actual meaning of your centimeters or inches or slice sizes is not clear. Which actual color space mathematical quantity is the size of your slice? Every color in a colorspace needs 3 number to be defined. One number shows only one coordinate. Those 16777216 available samples of sRGB color space in common 8 bit sRGB displays are are visually (and as deltaE in Lab color system) closer each other than the practically available 16777216 samples of DCI-P3 colorspace in 8 bit DCI-P3 displays. 8 bit per RGB channel is not a property of sRGB nor DCI-P3,  it's a limitation of  practical displays.

that's what I am saying I am talking about the practical scenario. The whole reason why colour gamut was invented in due to practical scenario. Ideally a device should be able to show all the colours which humans can see. Consider that we have a large gamut and a small gamut, since the gamut can only be divided into 16777216 pieces, the pieces in the larger gamut will be bigger in size.

@AnshulGupta the graphics card does not need to do the calculation with your input constraint. Since the color conversion is in fact done by graphics card it can and does calculate the color with higher bit precision (typically 12 bit). Obviously its not exactly the same as having a sRGB monitor, but the difference is very very small. Potentially smaller than differences between two random sRGB monitor. Point samples have no area.

@AnshulGupta No, you are not saying the same. Those 16777216 samples do not divide their color space, they are dimensionless points which have zero total area. Only infinite number of points can have some area. If you want something practically meaningful to be divided by colors  let it be a gradient in a color space. Some of us can see how gradients (without any noise dither) are banded on sRGB graphics. The actual divider there is not any available color sample, but the quantization treshold between 2 adjacent color samples.

@AnshulGupta (continued) Every available color X in a practical display, of course, defines a range of colors which should be approximated with X for the least possible deltaE error. In that sense every practically available color X divide the color space to three sets: 1) those who have X as the best available approximation 2) those who who have 2 or more as good available best approximations and X is one of them 3) those which should be approximated by some other available color than X for the least possible deltaE.
